# Out of memory exception in C# WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, memory

I've a C# wcf service in which my GetProducts() method has code as per below.

```
using (var client = CreateHttpClient("/myURL", string.Empty))
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress.AbsolutePath).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var products= response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Product>>().Result;
                    lstProducts.AddRange(products);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error fetching products...");
                }
            }
```

There's another method A() in this service that calls this method and it throws following out of memory exception:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal(IPrincipal principal, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start()
   at System.Net.TimerThread.Prod()
   at System.Net.TimerThread.TimerQueue.CreateTimer(Callback callback, Object context)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint..ctor(Uri address, Queue defaultIdlingQueue, Int32 defaultConnectionLimit, String lookupString, Boolean userChangedLimit, Boolean proxyServicePoint)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePointHelper(Uri address, Boolean isProxyServicePoint)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri address, IWebProxy proxy, ProxyChain& chain, HttpAbortDelegate& abortDelegate, Int32& abortState)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.FindServicePoint(Boolean forceFind)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartGettingResponse(RequestState state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartRequest(Object obj)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
MyService.ProductsManager.GetProducts()
--> (Inner Exception #0) System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal(IPrincipal principal, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start()
   at System.Net.TimerThread.Prod()
   at System.Net.TimerThread.TimerQueue.CreateTimer(Callback callback, Object context)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint..ctor(Uri address, Queue defaultIdlingQueue, Int32 defaultConnectionLimit, String lookupString, Boolean userChangedLimit, Boolean proxyServicePoint)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePointHelper(Uri address, Boolean isProxyServicePoint)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri address, IWebProxy proxy, ProxyChain& chain, HttpAbortDelegate& abortDelegate, Int32& abortState)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.FindServicePoint(Boolean forceFind)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartGettingResponse(RequestState state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartRequest(Object obj)<---
```

I'm already using the "using" block in GetProducts() method.So just wondering what else I could do in my code to prevent this out of memory exception?
Or could it be that there is a memory leak at the "myURL" service side?

Or would following help?
1.Change the build platform target to x64.
2.Add following in the service config file?

```
<runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />    
</runtime>
```

Please advise.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like the remote url that you are calling to get the list of products returns a huge response that cannot be loaded in memory. There's not much you could do unless stop loading the entire response in memory. Check if the remote endpoint supports pagination or some filtering and take advantage of it to reduce the size of the response.

Comment: You should really not be using `.Result`, WCF handles async functions just fine. Make your entry point `async Task<Products> GetProductsAsync()` then use async await all the way up the call stack. The client side code will ***not*** need to do any changes, it can still call `Products GetProducts()` because WCF will strip off the `Async` part of the name and make the return type look like just `Products` instead of `Task<Products>` automatically.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your inputs.Is the suggestion you provided would help resolve the outofMemory error or you're suggesting it as part of a good practice?

Comment: Looks obvious but did you verify the memory in machine running the service?